# Puedo usar un addEventListener de un elemento seleccionado creado por innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, api, eventos, foreach, innerhtml

Estoy consumiendo datos de una API de la cual estoy generando imágenes en mi html (con innerHTML), pero quería mostrar las imágenes mas grandes, usando una librería (sweetAlert)
y pretendía hacer esto, creando una variable que seleccione la clase de la imagen que se mostro en pantalla con innerHTML pero en consola me dice que addEventListener no puede leer datos nulos. y no se si haya alguna manera de poder hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Segun parece el addEventListener se ejecuta antes que los innerHTML que contienen las imágenes que tienen la clase que debería encontrar, y supongo que el setTimeout() tiene parte de culpa de eso. En lugar de usar el addEventListener en la propia clase de la imagen, deberias usarlo en algun elemento superior, como un div que esté desde el principio durante la carga, para poder hacer la delegación de eventos después sobre la clase de la imagen.

Comment: Intentare arreglarlo, Me siento imbécil al leer tu respuesta, muchísimas gracias brother!! me diste una idea (le pondré otro serTimeout con mayor  tiempo al addEventListener). si no probare de otra manera. Muchas Gracias!!!!

Comment: No debes sentirte eso ni mucho menos. La delegación por eventos en javascript no es tan obvia ni conocida por todos. Si lo buscas en [google](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=javascript+delegaci%C3%B3n+por+eventos)  encontrarás bastantes páginas que lo explican ampliamente.  Lo de usar otro setTimeout no se yo si es buena idea, prefiero la delegación por eventos en este caso.